# Unable to connect to MSK Kafka Broker after adding advertised.listener config

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have recently been adding `advertised.listeners` property to my MSK cluster configuration. The command used was

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-1.xxxxxxxxx.c4.kafka.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9094 \
--entity-type brokers \
--entity-name 1 \
--alter \
--command-config kafka.client.properties \
--add-config advertised.listeners=[CLIENT_SECURE://b-1.xxxxxxxxx.c4.kafka.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9002,REPLICATION://b-1-internal.xxxxxxxxx.kafka.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9093,REPLICATION_SECURE://b-1-internal.xxxxxxxxx.kafka.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9095]
```

However, now if I try to get the configuration back using the following command

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-1.xxxxxxxxx.kafka.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9002 \
  --entity-type brokers \
  --entity-name 1 \
  --describe \
  --all \
  --command-config kafka.client.properties
```

I get a message in the trace log saying `"Client is not ready to send to node"`.

Initially I thought this was to do with security groups but confirmed that they were open and allowing traffic. Any help would be as usual be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I feel like this should maybe be a question for MSK support directly

Comment: Lol yeah - Done that. They are also facing the same issue. Waiting for a detailed response.